# Добавление стилей при помощи React.createRef()

Tags: reactjs

Есть ли возможность добавить стилей на контейнер который выбран ссылкой при помощи createRef()

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t86sM.jpg)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1):

С помощью `ref` обновляем стили контейнера. Вы так имели ввиду?

```js
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    }
    this._ref = {};
  }
  
  changeStyle() {
   this._ref.classList.toggle('active')
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div 
        ref={(ref) => this._ref = ref}
        onMouseOver={this.changeStyle.bind(this)}
        onMouseOut={this.changeStyle.bind(this)}
       >
        <h2>Todos:</h2>
        
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.active {
  background-color: red;
}

.done {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

input {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```